# JavaScript: как реализовать фиксацию слайда в карусели

Tags: javascript

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть карусель. Необходимо добавить функционал фиксации позиции любого слайда по клику (не более одного одновременно). Все остальные слайды должны двигаться сквозь него. Пример: кликнули на слайд 3, он стал желтым, стоит на третьей позиции. Кликаем "Next", 3-й слайд стоит на месте, все остальные сдвинулись на одну позицию, т.е. видимый порядок цифр: 2 4 3 5 6... Таким образом, зафиксированный слайд всегда стоит неподвижно, на своём месте, в том числе во время анимации листания слайдера. Фиксация снимается по повторному клику, слайд остаётся на том же месте и двигается уже со всеми.

Подскажите как реализовать этот функционал на JS?

Comment: Покажите, как у вас сейчас эта карусель написана?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это лишь пример с массивом, но думаю аналогия должна быть ясна:

```
const arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
let selected = null;

const next = () => {
    for (let i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (i === selected) continue;

        const t = i - 1 === selected ? i - 2 : i - 1;
        if (t < 0) continue;

        const buff = arr[t];
        arr[t] = arr[i];
        arr[i] = buff;
    }

    console.log(arr);
}

const toggle = i => {
    selected = selected === i ? null : i;
}
```

можете запустить этот скрипт в браузере и через devTools 'потыкать' код.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь!